# PKC (non Diffie-Hellman) from Graph Isomorphism

Tags: public-key, trapdoor

A Diffie Hellman style approach is proposed in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408757/diffie-hellman-cryptography-based-on-graph-isomorphism but is broken easily.

Two graphs are isomorphic iff there adjacency matrices can be permuted to each other. GI has only quasipolynomial algorithms.

I wonder if there is a toy scheme (I know GI is not known to be average case secure) to illustrate with PK and SK to encrypt messages (similar to RSA or LWE etc) using GI based approach as trapdoor?